# datetime.now is 10 hours late only on the server, on the local machine sets right

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime, localization

i have a web application where the datetime.now is very important.
on my local machine it's sets datetime.now to the right time.
only when i use it on the server ( my server sits in europe, i'm in israel ) there is a 10 hours diffrence between the real time and the datetime.now
i've tried allready :

```
<globalization culture="he-IL" uiCulture="he-IL" />
```

also i've tried to set each page / set the datetime variables direct to local time :

```
DateTime example = DateTime.Now.ToLocal();
```

and still , nothing seems to work.
any suggestions?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

DateTime.Now **is** local, so converting to local is a no-op; if it isn't right, try DateTime.UtcNow, or combinations involving starting from UtcNow and applying ToLocal from there.

Also ensure the server's clock and timezone are correct.

To be honest, using UtcNow throughout may be easier.

Comment: thnks for the quick replay - but no.. i've tried every mix of those options and none of them got me the error fixed

Comment: @barak k; but what are you calling the "real time" here? And how is the server configured? Does the server think it is in Israel? Or...? Note the app's culture is not going to affect the system clock

Comment: what's so wierd about it - is that it's true! the datetime.now is local.. so it means that the local time on the server is no set right- when i use datepicker in the client side - the date is correct ( beacuse the machine interperate the local time) but every date that sits on the server side no. i don't get itl

Comment: @barak client-side date-picker probably uses a lot of client-side info, no?

Comment: i've set the app config to israel ( culture ) but in the server i didn't found a place to adjust my state. i'm using winhost servers , you have any idea how to set the clock on the server programaticly ?

Comment: @barak ben horin, physical location of machine has nothing to do with time zone set on it, it could be very well configured for India's half-an-hour offset timezone. Just do ALL your time calculations in UTC and live hapily thereafter.

Comment: I'm not familiar with windows, but usually you cannot change a server's clock unless you have administrator privileges. Just use UTC times, and convert it to the user's local timezone when you convert the date to a human-readable string.

Comment: Check that the account that is running your App/Class/Web has it's Regional Settings correct.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the application Culture changes how number, datetime etc etc are displayed

Does not affect time zone because a culture could be valid for different timezone.

You should handle datime as utc

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.aspx

```
var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("YOUR TIME ZONE ID");
var dateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, timezone)
```

Comment: the thing is.. that if i cannot apply it in the web.config then i'll have to do it in every page and it's the same as adding 10 hours to my DateTime varibles

Comment: as i commented in the DateTime.Now.AddHours(10) answer: what will happen when you change server or some admin adjust server timezone... and when daylight time saving comes?

Comment: how can i convert into datetime ? ( not ToLocalTime ) - directly to the time it keeps

Comment: @barakbenhorin var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("YOUR TIME ZONE");
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, timezone);

Answer (score 2):

If the server is 10 hours behind, it is going to return you its local time, not yours.  What if you add 10 hours to the server's local time to get your local time in Israel. You might have to give or take and hour if you have to observe daylight savings time.

```
var dt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(10);
```

Comment: :) i've thought about it.. but this project is realy big and i'm trying to avoid changing all of those places .. although i can just replace them.. in last option i'll do it thnks.

Comment: and what will happen when you change server or some admin adjust server timezone... and when daylight time saving comes?

Comment: good point... i guess i have extra few hours of work.. thnks and good night

Comment: @giammin - I agree with you, I don't think it is that good of a solutio, I was just trying to help with an alternate solution, no need to be rude and say it is dirt.  I think it is best to just work with UTC.  Time seems to give me the most trouble.

Comment: @Xaisoft i didn't want to be rude, I'm sorry if you have meant this way. Sometime you need to write dirty becouse it is the best option!